# Concurrent access to a TreeSet doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, synchronized, treeset

I'm creating a Java class IdGenerator that allocates a unique integer ID each time one is requested. It uses a TreeSet to store ranges of free IDs, and each time an ID is requested it looks in the set to find a range, allocates the first ID in the range, deletes the range, and adds a new range that is one smaller. The whole allocation process is synchronized on the set to ensure that different threads don't collide.

This worked fine when I was unit testing the class, but I have just run a test of a different class where an instance of the IdGenerator class is called ten times in quick succession, by different threads, and it returns the same value every time. Logging reveals that on each invocation, the set holding the free ranges has the same contents, although the lastId variable is different: -1 on the first invocation, 0 on the others. This seems to suggest that the different threads are using different copies of the set, although that's not what I would expect from the code.

I'm running using JRE 1.8.0_191, within Eclipse Neon 4.6.3 on Windows 10.

I've tried synchronizing on the generator object rather than the set, wrapping the TreeSet in a synchronizedSortedSet, and using a Lock object instead of the synchronized keyword. None of it made any difference.

```
private final SortedSet<Range> freeRanges = new TreeSet<>();
private int lastId;


public int allocateId() throws IllegalStateException
{
    int answer;
    synchronized (freeRanges)
    {
        LOG.debug("lastId = {}, freeRanges = {}", lastId, freeRanges);
        if (freeRanges.isEmpty())
            throw new IllegalStateException("All possible IDs are allocated");
        Range range = Stream
                .of(freeRanges.tailSet(new Range(lastId + 1)), freeRanges)
                .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
                .map(SortedSet::first)
                .findFirst()
                .get();
        answer = lastId = range.start;
        freeRanges.remove(range);
        if (range.start != range.end)
            freeRanges.add(new Range(range.start + 1, range.end));
        LOG.debug("Allocated {}, freeRanges = {}", answer, freeRanges);
    }
    return answer;
}
```

The log output is as shown below. I expect that on the nth invocation, the number allocated is n-1 and the set of free ranges is updated to show a range starting at n and ending at 100. But instead, what I see is this:

```
16:03:18.554 [main] DEBUG uk.org.thehickses.idgenerator.IdGenerator - lastId = -1, freeRanges = [Range [start=0, end=100]]
16:03:18.570 [main] DEBUG uk.org.thehickses.idgenerator.IdGenerator - Allocated 0, freeRanges = [Range [start=1, end=100]]
16:03:18.586 [main] DEBUG uk.org.thehickses.idgenerator.IdGenerator - lastId = 0, freeRanges = [Range [start=0, end=100]]
16:03:18.586 [main] DEBUG uk.org.thehickses.idgenerator.IdGenerator - Allocated 0, freeRanges = [Range [start=1, end=100]]
16:03:18.586 [main] DEBUG uk.org.thehickses.idgenerator.IdGenerator - lastId = 0, freeRanges = [Range [start=0, end=100]]
16:03:18.586 [main] DEBUG uk.org.thehickses.idgenerator.IdGenerator - Allocated 0, freeRanges = [Range [start=1, end=100]]
16:03:18.586 [main] DEBUG uk.org.thehickses.idgenerator.IdGenerator - lastId = 0, freeRanges = [Range [start=0, end=100]]
16:03:18.586 [main] DEBUG uk.org.thehickses.idgenerator.IdGenerator - Allocated 0, freeRanges = [Range [start=1, end=100]]
16:03:18.586 [main] DEBUG uk.org.thehickses.idgenerator.IdGenerator - lastId = 0, freeRanges = [Range [start=0, end=100]]
16:03:18.586 [main] DEBUG uk.org.thehickses.idgenerator.IdGenerator - Allocated 0, freeRanges = [Range [start=1, end=100]]
16:03:18.586 [main] DEBUG uk.org.thehickses.idgenerator.IdGenerator - lastId = 0, freeRanges = [Range [start=0, end=100]]
16:03:18.586 [main] DEBUG uk.org.thehickses.idgenerator.IdGenerator - Allocated 0, freeRanges = [Range [start=1, end=100]]
16:03:18.586 [main] DEBUG uk.org.thehickses.idgenerator.IdGenerator - lastId = 0, freeRanges = [Range [start=0, end=100]]
16:03:18.586 [main] DEBUG uk.org.thehickses.idgenerator.IdGenerator - Allocated 0, freeRanges = [Range [start=1, end=100]]
16:03:18.586 [main] DEBUG uk.org.thehickses.idgenerator.IdGenerator - lastId = 0, freeRanges = [Range [start=0, end=100]]
16:03:18.586 [main] DEBUG uk.org.thehickses.idgenerator.IdGenerator - Allocated 0, freeRanges = [Range [start=1, end=100]]
16:03:18.586 [main] DEBUG uk.org.thehickses.idgenerator.IdGenerator - lastId = 0, freeRanges = [Range [start=0, end=100]]
16:03:18.586 [main] DEBUG uk.org.thehickses.idgenerator.IdGenerator - Allocated 0, freeRanges = [Range [start=1, end=100]]
16:03:18.586 [main] DEBUG uk.org.thehickses.idgenerator.IdGenerator - lastId = 0, freeRanges = [Range [start=0, end=100]]
16:03:18.586 [main] DEBUG uk.org.thehickses.idgenerator.IdGenerator - Allocated 0, freeRanges = [Range [start=1, end=100]]
```

Comment: Your synchronization is fine (but you might as well declare the whole method synchronized). The error must be in the code inside the block. Do you really need all that stream processing? Wouldn't `freeRanges.first()` suffice?

Comment: For *grins*, what happens when you wrap the tree set in a synchronized set?

Comment: I could declare the whole method synchronized, but that would be equivalent to `synchronized (this)`, not `synchronized (freeRanges)`. I'm not a fan of `synchronized (this)` because it means that external code could also synchronize on my object; I prefer to synchronize on an object that only I know about,

Comment: All that stream processing is there to ensure that as far as possible, I cycle through all supported IDs before starting again from the beginning. But I just tried changing it to `freeRanges.first()` and it made no difference to the problem.

Comment: Why not just use a `Queue<Range>` (or even a `Deque<Range>`) and pop a range off then add it to the end of the queue? It would also mean you wouldn't need to synchronize the method body, if you used a threadsafe queue implementation.

Comment: As stated above, wrapping the tree set in a synchronized set makes no difference.

Comment: Okay; fair enough.  Mind posting some simple implementation of your `Range` class so we could also run it locally?

Comment: A `Queue<Range>` would make it more complicated to maintain the list of free ranges when it becomes more fragmented, and also more difficult to achieve the goal of cycling through all possible values before starting again at the beginning.

Comment: Full code is at https://github.com/hicksjduk/idgenerator. The Range class is an inner class of IdGenerator.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone who responded. I'm afraid that I may have misled you - I realised, while cycling home last night, that the problem is nothing to do with multiple calls to the `allocateId` method from different threads. The log I posted clearly shows that all those calls are made in the **same** thread (it is called "main").

And while cycling to work this morning, I realised what the problem was - it is that other threads are calling the `freeId` method which returns IDs to the `freeRanges` set. And in particular, the ID allocated by each call to `allocateId` is being freed **before** the next call to `allocateId`. That explains why `freeRanges` has the same contents each time `allocateId` is called.

I've made a simple change to ensure that when this happens, if the range that is found contains `lastId + 1` then that is the value allocated, even if it is not at the start of the range. And of course, if it isn't at the start of that range, the range is replaced in `freeRanges` with up to two new ranges - one containing all the numbers in the range that are less than the allocated number, and one containing all those that are more than it. This ensures that we cycle through all the available numbers as far as possible, and only if there are no free numbers that are greater than the last one allocated do we go back to the beginning.

Amended code is below. Clearly I should spend more time on my bike, and less in front of my computer!

```
public int allocateId() throws IllegalStateException
{
    int answer;
    synchronized (freeRanges)
    {
        LOG.debug("Allocating: lastId = {}, freeRanges = {}", lastId, freeRanges);
        if (freeRanges.isEmpty())
            throw new IllegalStateException("All possible IDs are allocated");
        int nextId = lastId + 1;
        Range range = Stream
                .of(freeRanges.tailSet(new Range(nextId)), freeRanges)
                .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
                .map(SortedSet::first)
                .findFirst()
                .get();
        answer = lastId = range.contains(nextId) ? nextId : range.start;
        freeRanges.remove(range);
        range.splitAround(answer).forEach(freeRanges::add);
        LOG.debug("Allocated {}, freeRanges = {}", answer, freeRanges);
    }
    return answer;
}
```